# How To Get DOM Parser To Wait For Scripts To Run Before Parsing Data

Tags: php, jquery, dom, html-parsing, tablesorter

Ive got a page with an html table that uses tablesorter and is sorted onload. I want my dom parser script to grab the rows from this table only after it has been sorted. Right now it is skipping the sort and grabbing the rows before.

Answer (score 1):

Use the sortEnd event

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // call the tablesorter plugin, the magic happens in the markup 
    $("table").tablesorter(); 
    //assign the sortStart event 
    $("table").bind("sortStart",function() { 
        // Do stuff when the sorting begin
    }).bind("sortEnd",function() { 
        // To stuff when the sorting ends
    }); 
});
```

Comment: "the magic happens in the markup"    - How does the markup work? Its not showing in the tablesorter documentation.

Comment: The "markup" means whatever data you have in the "table" in my example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the DOM Parser in Javascript, then try to add the `defer="defer"` attribute to the Javascript's tag.

If you are using the one in PHP, then you can try to call the function `sleep()` as many times as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can as well try to make some kind of data attribute flag like  on finished sorting event, and before php starts parsing, check, if it really can do it by checking this flag, if not, then wait again and try later.